# Distributional limits are unique (in law)?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I want to check that my proof of this is correct:
Suppose $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ are sequences of (real-valued) random variables. 
Suppose that $X_n = Y_n$ in law. 
Suppose $X_n \rightarrow X$ in law, and $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ in law. 
Then $X=Y$ in law.

**Proof:** Let $A$ denote the set of atoms of $X$ and $Y$. Then $A$ is countable, so the complement of $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
Hence the sigma algebra generated by the collection $\{(-\infty,b) : b \notin A \}$ equals the Borel sigma-algebra. This collection is closed under intersection. To prove that $X$ and $Y$ are equal in law, it therefore suffices to show that $P(X < b) = P(Y < b)$ for all $b \notin A$. For $b \notin A$, the interval $(-\infty,b)$ is a continuity set for both $X$ and $Y$. So 
$$
P(X<b) = \lim_n P(X_n < b)
$$
and
$$
P(Y<b) = \lim_n P(Y_n < b).
$$
But $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are equal in law so the two right-hand sides above are equal. Hence, so are the left-hand sides, completing the proof.

I've never seen this argument before so I'm worried I'm making a silly mistake.